# Obtain Private Key from inside app

Tags: android, certificate, x509certificate, private-key

Is there any way to get the private key that current APK was signed with?

The operation is completely safe, since any modification (injection) to app would need a new signing and new key pair. So if private key (that developer is aware of that) is accessible to the running code, it's only accessible to the original code not a malicious one.

`X509Certificate` allows access to PublicKey, but I need access to PrivateKey.

```
public static X509Certificate GetCertificate(Context context) {

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
    try {
        packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;

    byte[] cert = signatures[0].toByteArray();

    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert);


    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    try {
        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
    } catch(CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    X509Certificate c = null;

    try {
        c  = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(input);
    } catch(CertificateException e) {

    }

    return c;
}
```

**Edit:**
A side question can be:

Is there any way to ensure that currently running code is running inside the APK with the original certificate? 
(Everybody have access to public key, so it's not a good candidate to check against, but private key is only known by original developer which can protect it (in some way) and check package certification against that.)

Answer (score 1):

The private key is used only for signing the APK and never (in theory) leaves the place of signing. So it's not possible to recover it from the APK.

Update: and no, the code itself can't check the validity of its own image. If the image has been altered, it's trivial to remove the check as well.

Comment: If we had access to private key, only the original code could extract it and pass it to a native checker (very hard to decompile)

Comment: How comes that only the original code could extract it? Anything would be able to extract it. In any case the key is not there.

Comment: If it was there or if we could verify the running package with the public key, then since injecting or removing any code requires re-signing of the package, then the new private key is no longer valid

Comment: The code itself can't check the validity of its own image - this makes no sense cause the check is trivially removed.